# Passing Query Parameters in Ballerina HTTP Client

Tags: http, query-string, ballerina, ballerina-http

In Ballerina HTTP client, we can send requests using the following syntax:

```ballerina
Album[] albums = check albumClient->/albums;
```

But if we need to send query parameters with this request like this:

```
albums?genre=pop
```

How can we do this with the above syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done similar to how you pass named parameters into a method:

```ballerina
Album[] albums = check albumClient->/albums(genre = pop);
```

See the relevant [Ballerina By Example here](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-client-query-parameter/).